# Background image in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, background, glut, freeglut

I'm doing a 3D asteroids game in windows (using OpenGL and GLUT) where you move in space through a bunch of obstacles and survive. I'm looking for a way to set an image background against the boring bg color options. I'm new to OpenGL and all i can think of is to texture map a sphere and set it to a ridiculously large radius. What is the standard way of setting image bg in a 3d game?

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to draw two texture mapped triangles, whose coordinates are x,y = +-1, z=0, w=1 and where both camera and perspective matrices are set to identity matrix.

Of course in the context of a 'space' game, where one could want the background to rotate, the natural choice is to render a cube with cubemap (perhaps showing galaxies). As the depth buffering is turned off during the background rendering, the cube doesn't even have to be "infinitely" large. A unit cube will do, as there is no way to find out how close the camera is to the object.